# List type field in H2 using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am trying to learn Spring boot and H2 and i'd like to have an entity that one of its field contains a list of objects. The objects themselves are only contained in the surrounding entity (they are not reused) so optimally they shouldn't have a table of their own.
Something like this :

```
@Entityy
@Table(name="PERSON") 
pubic class Person{
     @Column(name="PERSON_NAME")
     private String name;
     @Column(name="PERSON_ADDRESS")
     private String address
     @Column(name="PERSON_JOBS")
     private List<Job> recentJobs;

     ....   setters and getters ....
}

public class Job{
   private String companyName;
   private String title;
   private int monthsOfEmploymens;

   ....  setters and getters ....         
}
```

Is the list type supported by H2? should this be parsed from/to JSON string/other?

Comment: `so optimally they shouldn't have a table of their own` - I don't really see why they shouldn't. It's a list, so it's normal to have them in a separated table.

Answer (score 0):

By using JPA 2.0 you can see [here](https://jazzy.id.au/2008/03/24/jpa_2_0_new_features_part_1.html) or perhaps you wanted to use a Map by using `@ElementCollection` annotation.

```
javax.persistence.ElementCollection

@ElementCollection
Map<Key, Job> recentJobs;
```